# How to solve CORS redirection with express js router?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth-2.0, cors, http-redirect

I'm trying to implement OAuth2 authentication. When I try to send Authorization code I get this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load link1.
>   Redirect from link1 to link2
>   has been blocked by CORS policy: Request requires preflight, which is
>   disallowed to follow cross-origin redirect.

My req/rsp looks like this:

> General: 
>   Request URL:link1 
>   Request Method:OPTIONS Status Code:204 No
>   Content Remote Address:
>
> Response Headers: HTTP/1.1 204 No Content X-Powered-By: Express
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * Access-Control-Allow-Methods:
>   GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE Access-Control-Allow-Headers:
>   content-type, sessionid Date:
>
> Request Headers: OPTIONS /authorize HTTP/1.1 Host: host Connection:
>   keep-alive Access-Control-Request-Method: POST Origin: origin_link
>   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,
>   like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.76 Safari/537.36
>   Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type, sessionid Accept: */*
>   Referer: origin_link/dialog Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
>   Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

Comment: If you upgrade to Chrome 57, you should no longer hit that “Request requires preflight, which is disallowed to follow cross-origin redirect.” error. (The spec used to require browsers to disallow following cross-origin redirects from preflights, but was subsequently changed, and after the Chrome 56 release, the Chrome source was updated to match the current spec requirements.)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you have not configured express to accept CORS request.

In a small project, I had to configure CORS request in an Express application. My code was:

```
// Enable CORS
app.use((req, res, next) => {
   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST,DELETE');
   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested With, Content-Type, Accept');
   next();
});
```

`app` is a variable corresponding to an Express instance.

Moreover, I did find an npm package to set CORS request to an express app, but I have never used it:
https://github.com/expressjs/cors

Comment: Thank you for quick response, but I already tried all of that and it still doesn't work. I think that the problem is in redirecting, because in CORS doc, it says that when status code is 3xx just refuse the connection, but I can't figure out how to resolve it.

Comment: OK I see, usually when you use CORS, it's because you use AJAX requests. So you can doing a "fake" redirection, so it is not express who redirect but javascript in client side. When client receive your "fake" redirection, javascript change the page content.

Comment: Not really @NikhilAggala, you should pose your own question on StackOverflow and describe your problem, the community will quickly respond to you. In my opinion this topic is too old, no other work will come.